# How does imshow handle the alpha channel with an M x N x 4 input?

Tags: python, matplotlib

GH issue [#3343](http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3343)

---

I am using the `imshow` function in matplotlib to visualize some data. What I have are two arrays, *A* and *B*, that are the same size. I would like to use a colormap to show scalar values in *A*, and I would like to use the alpha channel to show the scalar values in *B*. In other words, if the value at a given coordinate in both *A* and *B* is large, then the pixel in the plot will be bright green and opaque. If it is large in *A* and not *B*, then it will be bright green but mostly transparent. And if it is large in *B* and not *A*, then it will be opaque but white.

However, the resulting image is not what I am expecting. My input data is called `d`, and it is a combination of the RGB values that result from mapping the *A* array with a matplotlib colormap (i.e. `mpl.cm.BuGn(A)`) and the *B* array.

Here I'm going to plot the full image (what I want to actually use), the RGB image (*A*, mapped with `BuGn`), and the alpha-providing array (*B*, with a grayscale colormap).

```
f, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(5, 2.5))

ax0.imshow(d)
ax1.imshow(d[..., :-1])
ax2.imshow(d[..., -1])
```

[image]

I am confused about where the splotchy gray junk in the full image is coming from, since there aren't any values in the colormap that are those colors. To show this effect more dramatically, I can change the bounds of the colormap so they are far away from the extremes of the data and re-plot:

[image]

I don't understand why pixels that are white with a large alpha value show up as gray. Opaque white should still be white.

Note that this behavior is different than if I plot the RGB component array and lower the transparancy with the `alpha` kwarg, i.e. `ax2.imshow(d[..., :-1], alpha=.3)`:

[image]

Comment: Weird. Can reproduce using a simple gradient as well, with no colormap: `d = np.ones((100, 100, 4)); d[..., -1] = np.linspace(0, 1, num=100); plt.imshow(d)`.

Comment: @DanAllan It is just due to the default white canvas color in matplotlib.

Comment: That is not the way transparency is treated in any imaging software I have used.

Comment: @DanAllan Perhaps it is premultiplying?  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx

Comment: Also see https://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg22377.html

Comment: How many pixels do you have and how fast do you need this to be?  That is, is this a 'generate figures for paper' type problem or a user-interface type problem?  If you can give up speed (and have small images) try `PatchCollection` or just drawing lots of patches.

Comment: Also created an issue https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3343

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but the downside is that it constrains the choices of interpolation to nearest neighbor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first answer was completely wrong, so here's my new attempt.

DaveAllen's comment above accurately reproduces the issue.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.ones((100, 100, 4), dtype=np.uint8)*255
d[:, :, 3] = np.linspace(0, 255, num=100)
plt.imshow(d, interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Produces:
[image]

You would expect a white image on a white background with variable alpha to be completely white.  And that would be the case with "straight" alpha.

It would seem that matlplotlib's graphics backend is displaying the image assuming "premultiplied" alpha, which means that the alpha affects the color of the image.  This would explain the image above.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx
https://www.mail-archive.com/matplotlib-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg22377.html

Pixels that are (1.0,1.0,1.0,0.5), when displayed, have their color first multiplied by their alpha channel, so they appear (0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), gray.

The pixels on the right are opaque and white, so they appear white.  The pixels on the left are displayed black and transparent so they appear the same as the background color, which is white.

The pixels in the middle are grey because they are displayed neither white nor transparent.

Comment: I don't think that's quite right, just because you don't see the same thing if you do `ax.imshow(d[..., :-1]], alpha=0.3)`. I have edited the question to show the result and how it contrasts with the full image.

Comment: @mwaskom: Yes, you are seeing this behavior because the axis background in matplotlib is white.  Change your axis color to black with fig.axes[0].set_axis_bgcolor("black") and you will see what I mean.

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to the difference between the plots above. The axis background is white in all of them.

Comment: I'm not doing any downvoting here, but I am pretty sure your statement in bold is wrong. In every imaging program I've ever uses, a white pixel with alpha 0 will be transparent, not black. And the background is white.

Comment: So this explanation makes a lot more sense, but it doesn't quite explain why `ax.imshow(..., alpha=.3)` looks good but adding an alpha channel to the image doesn't. Is the premultiplying behavior configurable?

Answer (score 4):

The revised answer by the venerable ballsdotballs seems plausible. From that mailing list post, it looks like handling of alpha values was not carefully thought out. Further, from the example in the original post, it seems to me that the `alpha` arg in `imshow` is composited differently than alpha numbers provided in RGBA data.

To work around whatever blending Agg is doing, one could avoid alpha and do the compositing manually.

```
A = np.tile(np.linspace(0, 1, num=100), (100, 1))  # gradient
B = A.T
d = plt.cm.BuGn(A)
d[..., -1] = B

composite = (d[..., :-1] * d[..., -1].reshape(100, 100, 1) +
    (1 - d[..., -1]).reshape(100, 100, 1))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2)
axes[0].imshow(d)
axes[1].imshow(composite)
```

[image]

I'm sure there's a better way to do the reshaping, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: This answers the question as posed; sadly for me I actually need the alpha because there's a background image that I want to be able to see in regions where *B* is low (a brain). But this tells me I'll have to pursue a different strategy.

Comment: I guess you could composite the image in the same way that I've implicitly composited an array of 1's here.