# Interactively changing the alpha value of matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've looked at the documentation, but I can't seem to figure out if this is possible -

I have a dataset, with `x` and `y` values and discrete `z` values. Multiple pairs of `(x,y)` share the same `z` value. What I want to do is when I mouseover one point with a particular `z` value, the `alpha` of all the points with the same `z` values goes to 1 - *i.e*., If all the alpha values are initially 0.5, I'd like only the points with the same z value to go to 1.

Here's a minimal working example to illustrate what I'm talking about :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x  = np.random.randn(100)
y  = np.random.randn(100)

z   = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
z   = np.repeat(z, 10)

im = plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, alpha = 0.5)
plt.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: The easiest way is to pass in a list of RGBA values for each marker.  The `alpha` kwarg applies to the _whole_ artist during compositing .

Comment: @tcaswell I briefly experimented with that - whilst it's possible to set the individual RGB values for each point, it seems that the global `alpha` value set for the collection overrides any manual changes to the alpha channel for each point.

Comment: My understand was that they stacked

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089068/how-does-imshow-handle-the-alpha-channel-with-an-m-x-n-x-4-input and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3343 and links contained for more than you ever wanted to know about how mpl does alpha blending.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably fake what you want to achieve using a second plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Z = np.zeros(1000, dtype = [("Z", int), ("P", float, 2)])
Z["P"] = np.random.uniform(0.0,1.0,(len(Z),2))
Z["Z"] = np.random.randint(0,50,len(Z))

def on_pick(event):
    z = Z[event.ind[0]]['Z']
    P = Z[np.where(Z["Z"] == z)]["P"]
    selection_plot.set_data(P[:,0],P[:,1])
    plt.draw()


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), facecolor='white')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', on_pick)
ax = plt.subplot(111, aspect=1)
ax.plot(Z['P'][:,0], Z['P'][:,1], 'o', color='k', alpha=0.1, picker=5)

selection_plot, = ax.plot([],[], 'o', color='black', alpha=1.0, zorder=10)
plt.show()
```